# Creating a histogram of probabilities with prediction result

Tags: r, graph, plot, model, histogram

i have a model of svm and i would like to have the prediction results shown as a data frame instead of a model

```
model <- svm(training$classe ~., data = training, probability=TRUE)
pred<- (model, testing, probability = TRUE)
hist(pred)
```

Currently if i do

```
class(pred) #it shows a factor.
```

If i run pred

```
>pred
1 
A 
attr(,"probabilities")
          A            B            C            D            E
1 0.9995978 0.0002552521 2.157329e-05 3.019972e-06 0.0001223695
Levels: A B C D E
```

What i would need is a data frame to plot a histogram of 5 bins with each bin as a class label and their frequency would be their probabilities.

```
There are 5 class labels A to E
```

I do not necessarily have to use histogram. Any other plots would be fine too.

Comment: Would `barplot(pred)` be a start?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Could you explain more. I tried using barplot but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you are getting this result:

```
library(e1071)

set.seed(357)
tds <- sample(1:nrow(iris), 10)
iris.train <- iris[-tds, ]
iris.test <- iris[tds, ]
model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris, probability = TRUE)

predict(model, newdata = iris.test, probability = TRUE)

        17          9         42         34         96         68        135        107        111        140 
    setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa versicolor versicolor  virginica  virginica  virginica  virginica 
attr(,"probabilities")
         setosa versicolor   virginica
17  0.975617665 0.01471624 0.009666098
9   0.965967587 0.02223986 0.011792550
42  0.862565881 0.11739501 0.020039111
34  0.967946010 0.01838272 0.013671268
96  0.015016432 0.98088056 0.004103008
68  0.010676592 0.98680145 0.002521956
135 0.010729187 0.33894236 0.650328456
107 0.010702200 0.37824730 0.611050505
111 0.009757802 0.06857737 0.921664824
140 0.007114249 0.01210420 0.980781547
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

If I turn off probabilities, I can predict a class, calculate frequencies using `table` and draw a barplot.

```
model2 <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)
barplot(table(predict(model2, newdata = iris.test)))
```

Comment: yes but i am trying to plot a probability graph of each class label. Say for example, the probability of it being in class A is 0.2 and class B is 0.4, it would show on a histogram like 0.2 and 0.4

Comment: @aceminer so you would like to convert the frequencies to probabilities? Divide the result by its sum and you're done.

Comment: But when i tried to extract the probabilities out. It showed as a factor. in other words i could not get the individual probabilities as a vector or data frame or anything besides a factor